# Error 1064 at line 6 while creating sql table

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
customer_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
customer_email VARCHAR(100) NULL,
street_address VARCHAR(50) NULL,
city VARCHAR(50) NULL,
province CHAR(2) NULL,
postal_code CHAR(6) NULL,
);
```

As said above I get error 1064 when attempting to create a new table and am not sure why. The name "city" isn't a reserved word, and the definitions aren't depreciated to my knowledge

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove last comma after postal_code

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
customer_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
customer_email VARCHAR(100) NULL,
street_address VARCHAR(50) NULL,
city VARCHAR(50) NULL,
province CHAR(2) NULL,
postal_code CHAR(6) NULL
);
```

Comment: This one worked, but now its saying the table "customer" already exists for some reason. Error 1050 now

Comment: it means table created. Check in My SQL Tables. If it is already there then no need to create it again. if there is any change in schema, you can alter it.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    customer_email VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    street_address VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    city VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    province CHAR(2) NULL,
    postal_code CHAR(6) NULL
);
```

Comment: It' coming up with the same error, same place too

Answer (score 1):

Last comma need to be removed

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
customer_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
customer_email VARCHAR(100) NULL,
street_address VARCHAR(50) NULL,
city VARCHAR(50) NULL,
province CHAR(2) NULL,
postal_code CHAR(6) NULL
);
```